# VBA For loop IF Instr not finding substring

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, if-statement

Afternoon,

The cell in D2 contains "CH-SFDC-ENH-XXX-ALM-China Legal Case Enhancement"
The formula is looking for the substring "-SFDC-" which is contained in the cell and will assign a value to the specified cell HX. When running it does not find the substring and assigns the value unknown.

Below is the formula. What am I missing?

```
lastrow = Worksheets("SFDC").UsedRange.Rows.Count
Set Check = Range("D2:D" & lastrow)
cellvalue = 2

For Each cell In Check

       'I have also tried "SFDC"
    If InStr(cell, "*-SFDC-*") Then
        Cells(cellvalue, "H") = "SFDC"

    ElseIf InStr(cell, "*-FE-*") Then
        Cells(cellvalue, "H") = "FE"

    Else
        Cells(cellvalue, "H") = "Unknown"

    End If
    cellvalue = cellvalue + 1
Next
```

EDIT resolved both worked

```
If InStr(cell, "-SFDC-") Then
or
If cell.Value Like "*-SFDC-*" Then
```

Comment: `IF cell.Value Like  "*-SFDC-*" Then `

Comment: hmm, didn't think about using that. Thanks!
Any input on why the InStr doesn't work?

Comment: You have the * in your instr comparison.  Try just If InStr(cell,"-SFDC-") then.

Comment: Thanks guys, both worked  
@ScottCraner from the removed post but thanks! for the info about wildcards not working with InStr